# Get all objects that have entries in another model

Tags: python, django

```
class Event(HashidModel, TimeStampedModel):
    organizer = models.ForeignKey(
        "organizers.Organizer", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="events"
    )
```

How do I get all organizers, that have existing events? My challenge is that I have to go through the organizer (I can't start from the event mode.l)

`organizer = Organizer.objects.all()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Organizer.objects.filter(
    events__isnull=False
).distinct()
```

This works since we perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the `Event` table, and then filter such that we only retrieve items for wich the `id` of the `Event` is `NOT NULL`. We then take the `DISTINCT` objects to avoid retrieving the `Organizer` multiple times, one per `Event`.

Normally Django will optimize this to an `INNER JOIN`.